# Como colocar um evento de MouseCliked em uma tabela usando JavaFX

Tags: java, table, javafx

Estou tentando colocar um evento de MouseCliked na minha tabela porém da esse erro:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
```

Meu método está assim:

```
private void tblArquivosMouseCliked(ActionEvent event) {

        System.out.println("Click Detectado");

    }
```

E no Scene Builder:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém pode ajudar? Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu método deveria ser da seguinte forma:

```
@FXML
public void tblArquivosMouseCliked(MouseEvent event) {
    System.out.println("Click Detectado");
}
```

Comment: Agora está dando esse erro:
`javafx.fxml.LoadException: Error resolving onMouseClicked='#tblArquivosMouseCliked', either the event handler is not in the Namespace or there is an error in the script.`

Comment: @Techies desculpa, eu não tinha percebido que o método estava `private` só tinha percebido o ActionEvent, corrigido. A propósito, pretendo dar uma resposta mais completa em breve, mas por hora é o que eu consigo responder :)

Comment: Muito Obrigado, ok estarei esperando :D